# is this conjecture true or false?

Tags: calculus, conjectures

I want to know if this conjecture istrue or false

$$\Large e^{\frac{ \ln x}{x}} \notin \mathbb{Z} $$

for every $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1,-1,0\} $

Comment: How are you defining $\ln x$ for $x \le 0$? Also, what have you tried, what is the context of the problem?

Comment: It's true.  And $x$ must be positive, so that $\ln x $ is defined.  OTOH, I don't know what happens if you allow complex values for the logarithm.

Comment: @Michael for $\exp$ to be real (which is necessary), $\Im(\ln(x)/x) = -\arg x \Im x \in 2\pi\mathbb Z$
So for $\Im x \neq 0$ you can construct the points of interest given any $\nu\in S^1$ by scaling with a real multiple, i.e.
$$x = \nu \cdot \frac{2\pi k}{\Im\nu \arg \nu}$$

Comment: Well, $x^{1/x}$ ( in $[1, \infty) $, of course, is bounded above by 2, so that does not leave many options.But I don't yet have a proof for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask this only for $x>0$, as the expression is not well defined otherwise. You can rule out the case $x\in(0,1)$ easily, since it implies $\ln(x)/x<0$. Now find the maximum of $\ln(x)/x$ on $(1,\infty)$, and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Firstly, show that as a real function, ${\rm dom}(f) = \mathbb R^{>0}$
Secondly, show that $f(\mathbb R^{>0}) = (0, e^{\frac1e})$ and conclude by
$$f(\mathbb R^{>0}) \cap \mathbb Z = \{1\}$$
and $f^{-1}(1) = \{1\}$

Answer (score 0):

Just like Oliver Bel said, $e^{lnx/x} = x^{1/x}$.

Now, suppose there exist an integer N such that $N^x=x, N>1$. Try to graph the equations $y = N^x$ and $y = x$. It should be clear that no such integer exists.

Answer (score 0):

$x^{1/x}$ takes the value 1 at 1, and decreases after $e$, since its derivative is:

$-x^{\frac{1}{x}-2}(logx-1) $.  And $-x^{\frac{1}{x}-2}$ is always $<0$ , and $logx-1>0$ is positive for $x>e$. So we only need to worry about $e^{1/e}~1.44....<2$, all  computations thanks to Wolfram. So only possible integer value in $[1,\infty)$ is $1$